# Is $x*y=x$ associative and/or commutative on $\Bbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, binary-operations

Let $*:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ on the integers by the formula $x*y=x$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$. Decide whether $*$ is associative and/or commutative.

To the best of my understanding this means I'm taking a Cartesian product $(x,y)$ and sending it to $x$. I think this would be both associative and commutative since it appears this only happens when the pair is $(x,0)$ with $(0,0)$.

Associativity means $(x*y)*z=x*(y*z)$.
By this, if $x=(x,0), y=(0,0)$, then $z$ must also be $(0,0)$ by necessity which clearly is associative.

Commutativity means $x*y=y*x$.
If $x=(x,0)$, then $y$ must be $(0,0)$. This is clearly commutative.

I'm struggling to put this into formal terminology. Are my thoughts correct? If not, what adjustments should I consider?

Comment: $*$ is just some operation just as multiplication, addition are operations. When we write $3+4$, we don't usually think of a map from the Cartesian product $(3,4)$ to $7$, we just think of $3+4$. Same here.

Comment: You can never prove a general property with an example

Comment: One way to approach it as just 'string' replacement. When you see $x * y$ replace it by $x$. Then $x * (y * z) = x * (y) = x * y = x $.

Comment: I don't understand "this only happens when the pair is $(x,0)$ with $(0,0)$." What does "this"mean here? I hope it doesn't refer to sending $(x,y)$ to $x$, since the problem says this happens "for any $x,y\in\mathbb Z$." Also "a Cartesian product $(x,y)$" doesn't make sense because $(x,y)$ is not a Cartesian product;  it's one element of a Cartesian product.

Comment: Thanks, I misread the definition of $*$, all your responses make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is associative, because for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$, you have that
$$x\star (y\star z)=x\star y=x=(x\star y)\star z$$
It is not commutative, for example because
$$0\star 1=0\neq 1=1\star 0$$

Comment: Last line starts with $0*1$

Comment: Much appreciated. I'm slightly new to problems such as these, when I see general elements sometimes I talk myself out of the solution.